# Consecutive Prime Factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

**Problem**: Can all prime factors of $(a^{b \times c} - 1)$ be consecutive primes when $a, b, c \geq 3$  ?

Comment: Would things like $17^2\cdot 19^7\cdot 23$ be allowed as factorization or only $17\cdot 19\cdot 23$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  ,  yes, power factor  is allowed.