# Prove, $\gcd((a^b-1)/(a-1), (a^c-1)/(a-1))=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem  :** Prove (or disprove) that,  $\gcd((a^b-1)/(a-1),  (a^c-1)/(a-1))=1$ (greatest common divisor), 
when $a, b, c $ are prime numbers and $a, b, c \geq 3, b \neq c$.  $(a^b-1),  (a^c-1)$ are factors of $(a^{bc}-1)$.

Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2162500/179940) to see the related  question .

Comment: So what if $a=b=c=3$? Then gcd=26, no? Maybe I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Second part, likewise divide, e.g. $(a^{bc}-1)/(a^b-1) = a^{bc-b} + a^{bc-2b} + ... + a^{bc-cb}$, that last term being equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n) = (a^n-1)/(a-1).\,$ By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7479/242) $\,(f(b),f(c)) = f((b,c)) = f(1) =1$

Answer (score 0):

assume $c > b$

Also gcd $(a, 1 + a + ... + a^b) = 1$

Let $x = (a^c - 1)/(a-1) = 1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^{c-1}$

Let $y = (a^b - 1)/(a-1) = 1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^{b-1}$

$gcd(x,y) = gcd(x-y, y) = gcd((a^b + ... + a^{c-1}), y) = gcd ((a^b(1 + a + ... + a^{c-b-1}), y) = gcd((1 + a + ... + a^{c-b-1}), y)$

as we keep doing, we get $gcd(x,y) = gcd((1 + a + ... + a^{k-1}), (1 + a + ... + a^{b-1}))$ with $k < b$ 
eventually ending up with $gcd(1 + a + ... + a^m, a^n) = 1$ for some integer $m$ and $n$.

Therefore there is no common factor between $x$ and $y$.